# Am I able to view a list of devices by partition in iothub?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I have 2 nodes of a cluster receiving messages from iothub. I split their responsibility by partition. Node 1 reads from partitions 1,3,5,7,9 and the other 2,4,6,8, and 0. Recently, my partition 8 stops responding until I stop my code and restart it. It seems like a device is sending a message that locks up the partition. What I want to do is list all devices in my partition 8. Is that possible? Is there a cloud shell command to get those devices in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will help you, but you can see the partition on the incoming messages.  For example you could use Azure Stream Analytics to see the partitions using this query:

```
Select GetMetadataPropertyValue(IoTHub, '[IoTHub].[ConnectionDeviceId]') as DeviceId, partitionId
from IoTHub
```

Also, if you run locally in VisualStudio it will tell you which device is sending malformed JSON.  eg.

[Warning] 10/21/2021 9:12:54 AM : **User Warning** Source 'IoTHub' had 1 occurrences of kind 'InputDeserializerError.InvalidData' between processing times '2021-10-21T15:12:50.5076449Z' and '2021-10-21T15:12:50.5712076Z'. Could not deserialize the input event(s) from resource 'Partition: [1], Offset: [455266583232], SequenceNumber: [634800], **DeviceId: [DeviceName]**' as Json. Some possible reasons: 1) Malformed events 2) Input source configured with incorrect serialization format

Also check your "Activity Log" blade in the ASA job.  It may have more details for you.

Comment: This isn't what I asked for specifically, but I think this will give me what I need to answer the question I was ACTUALLY asking.